# Elementary questions about Airline example on Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I am still at the learning stage of crossfilter and D3.

I have two questions about the example provided on [Crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/)

For the [example](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/gh-pages/index.html) they provided

1 . line 285:

`var list = d3.selectAll(".list").data([flightList]);`

In D3 wiki, `selection.data([values[, key]])`  The specified values is an array of data values, such as an array of numbers or objects, or a function that returns an array of values.

But flightList does not returns an array of values, and the augment for flightList is div.

2 . line 499:

`dimension.filterRange(extent);`

Why is there no function called for updating bar graphs by barPath()? How could the bar graph updating itself with data changed? So if the data changed, the graph will be updated at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

'list' is a selection that has a one-element array as it's data, and the single element is the function flightList.

On line 301, we see 'list.each(render);', meaning that the render function is called for each element in the 'list' selection, passing in its datum (flightList) as the first argument to the render function.

Therefore line 295 in the 'render(method)' function, which is 'd3.select(this).call(method);' can be more or less rewritten in the context of the list as 'd3.select(".list").call(flightList);', which calls the flightList function passing in the '.list' div as the argument. The flightList function then proceeds to build up the list of flights on top of that div.

At least, that's my reading. IMO, that code is very elegant and general, but extremely hard to follow as an example.

2.

Line 281 sets up an event listener on all the charts that re-renders everything (the 'renderAll' function) whenever a brush moves or finishes moving.

Comment: Yes, I agree the code is very elegant, general and hard to follow. Thanks for your explanation for the first question. So, datum is just a reference to an object? The object could be a function or a number. For the second question, when users brush, will all functions registered for events "brush" and "brush.chart" be called？

Comment: On the first question, selection.datum directly sets the data object of a particular element. It can be any JS value, including an object, an array, or a function. It is discussed in the d3.js API documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum  Are you familiar with the data join concept? There are a bunch of great tutorials and examples here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials  On the second question: The 'renderAll' function is called, which then calls the render function on each list and bar chart.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the naming of an event. A function registered for "brush.chart", then both "brush" and "brush.chart" will trigger this function?

Comment: The function is registered on the 'brush' and the 'brushend' event with line 281, isn't it? - "function(chart) { chart.on("brush", renderAll).on("brushend", renderAll); }"

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I just wonder which function will be called first.

Comment: Whether 'brush' or 'brush.chart' is called first? Not sure. I assume brush.chart in this case, though I'm not clear on why 'brush.chart' ever gets called :-/